# Can't install any Linux distro on my laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, uefi

I am unable to use any Linux distro on my laptop. when I try to install any Linux distro I get a black screen. and I can't boot with try without installing mode. When I choose to try without installing mode that time I also get a black screen

Tool I used for making USB bootable: Rufus, win32disk imager, Universal USB Installer,UNetbootin.

System specs

ASUS ROG GL503VD
  Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7300HQ CPU @2.50GHZ -3.50GHZ
  RAM: 8GB
  System type: 640bit
  BIOS: UEFI
  Partition type: GPT
  GPU: Nvidia 1050

I already tried `nomodeset`, and I already tried installing with CSM after no result I tried it with UEFI boot.

Comment: thanks for replying but I already tried the nomodeset method, I already tried installing with CSM  after no result I tried it with UEFI boot currently my problem is your 3rd option -> Black screen
or
"you need to load kernel first" and "can not read file/cd0" errors
when installing to an UEFI capable machine:

Comment: I can't understand from your question, what you did and what worked or did not work. Do you get a back screen when booting from USB or after installation when booting from the internal disk? Did you try to install or boot in text-mode ?

Comment: when I try to install ubuntu in my laptop there is a black screen but when I use a flashlight on my laptop screen then I barely able to see a menu which asks to try or install I get this same problem with Kali Linux also

Comment: There is something odd about my lenovo that both Linux and Windows think that maximum brightness = maximum darkness, and I have to turn the brightness down in order to make the screen brighter... have you got a brightness button on your laptop keyboard you can play with and see if it helps? Or a turn screen on/off button?

Comment: yep i tried it but on installing time they don't work

Comment: when I search the internet with the two search terms: "ASUS ROG GL503VD" "linux" I get various interesting postings, for example this one: https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?81702-Linux-installation-in-ASUS-ROG-GL552VW-DH71#post564158
did you search around the internet for those two search terms and follow the suggested instructions?